# How to run a cursor inside a procedure in SQL Server

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I create these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE STUD 
(
    ST_NO NUMBER(4), 
    NAME VARCHAR2(20), 
    CITY VARCHAR2(20), 
    TEL NUMBER(9), 
    SEX VARCHAR2(10)
); 

INSERT INTO STUD VALUES(1, 'hamda', 'alburimi', 98765, 'f');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES(2, 'fooz', 'sohar', 98765, 'f');
INSERT INTO STUD VALUES(3, 'ali', 'alburimi', 98765, 'm');

CREATE TABLE soh_STUDENT AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM STUD
    );
```

Then I did a cursor inside a procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SOH_MEMBER IS

CURSOR studC IS
SELECT* from STUD;
BEGIN
  for c1   IN  studC
LOOP
  IF C1.CITY = 'sohar'
  THEN INSERT INTO SOH_STUDENT (NAME, TEL, SEX)
  VALUES( C1.NAME,  C1.TEL, C1.SEX);
  end if;
  END LOOP;
  END SOH_MEMBER;
```

and I want to know how I can show the result of this procedure?

I mean how I can show NAME, TEL and SEX only for CITY = 'sohar' in SOH_STUDENT table??

Comment: Are you sure you are in SQL Server?  `Create Or Replace` is not in Sql Server - I have encountered that syntax in Oracle.

Comment: in sql server you would have ALTER PROCEDURE instead

Comment: `create or replace`  and `varchar2` are **Oracle** - not SQL Server ...

Comment: this is a case of going around the block to go next door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the output like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SOH_MEMBER IS

CURSOR studC IS
SELECT* from STUD;
BEGIN
  for c1   IN  studC
LOOP
  IF C1.CITY = 'sohar'
  THEN INSERT INTO SOH_STUDENT (NAME, TEL, SEX)
  VALUES( C1.NAME,  C1.TEL, C1.SEX);
  end if;
  END LOOP;
  END SOH_MEMBER;

/* show the output */
Select * From SOH_STUDENT
```

But you can actually do the whole thing much faster this way (OTTOMH):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SOH_MEMBER IS

Insert Into SOH_STUDENT (NAME, TEL, SEX)
SELECT NAME, TEL, SEX
from STUD
Where CITY = 'sohar'

Select * From SOH_STUDENT
```